# Get Network based on IP and CIDR in powershell

Tags: powershell

I need to find the Net ID of my current network, but there are no way for me to get it with the cmdlets that I'm aware about.

For example, I have the host IP 192.168.0.1 and the CIDR /24, so the netID would be 192.168.0.0, but where would I find that just by a cmdlet?

Answer (score 0):

You can use NetAdapter module to get Adapter/IP Information. But you will not get a Network address directly.

```
Get-NetIPAddress -ifIndex $yournetworkadapterhere
```

It will provide `IPAddress` and `Prefixlength` = net mask.

Have a look at [this blogpost](http://blog.tyang.org/2012/02/09/powershell-script-calculate-first-and-last-ip-of-a-subnet/), which shows, how to get starting address = Network address you want and ending address of an address+netmask couple.